# Unit test $formatters in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a simple validator that checks an input against a regex:

```
.directive('test', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

        ctrl.$setValidity('namePattern', true);

        function checkValid(name) {
            console.log('checkValid executed');
            if (!name || ctrl.$pristine) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('namePattern', true);
                return name;
            }
            var test = /^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/;
            ctrl.$setValidity('namePattern', test.test(name));
            return name;
        }

        // called when value changes via code/controller
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(checkValid);
        // called when value changes in input element
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(checkValid);
    }
  };
});
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/1uv79jnL/1/)

I want to unit test this directive, and have the following:

```
function initState() {
  angular.mock.module('app');
  angular.mock.inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $timeout){
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    $rootScope.safeApply = function(cb) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$digest();
      });
    };

    $scope.model = {
      instanceName: ''
    };

    var tmpl = angular.element('<form name="form">' +
      '<input ng-model="model.instanceName" name="instanceName" test>' +
      '</form>'
    );

    element = $compile(tmpl)($scope);
    $scope.$apply();
    form = $scope.form;
  });
}
beforeEach(initState);
```

However, changes to the model don't trigger `checkValid`.  I've tried directly setting a property on the model:

```
it('should trigger a change resulting in an invalid state', function () {
  $scope.model.instanceName = 'this is an invalid name';
  $scope.$digest();
  expect(form.instanceName.$valid).to.be.false;
});
```

as well as monkeying around with `$modelValue`:

```
it('should trigger a change resulting in an invalid state', function () {
  form.instanceName.$modelValue = 'this is an invalid name';
  $scope.$digest();
  expect(form.instanceName.$valid).to.be.false;
});
```

I have also tried triggering the `input` event through `element.triggerHandler`.

How can I trigger a model change so that `checkValid` runs via `$formatters`?

(This is using Angular 1.2.23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your directive sets the input to be valid if it's pristine. In the case of the unit test you've written, it will always be pristine as the user hasn't interacted with it.

If you want the directive to continue how it is now, then in the test test you can force the input to not be pristine: (I'm using Jasmine here)

```
it('should trigger a change resulting in an invalid state', function () {
  $scope.model.instanceName = 'this is an invalid name';
  form.instanceName.$pristine = false;
  $scope.$digest();
  expect(form.instanceName.$valid).toEqual(false);
});
```

This can be seen working at http://plnkr.co/edit/TEd91POjw9odNHSb6CQP?p=preview

Since your directive explicitly assumes the input is valid for model changes for an input in a pristine state, then actually I think a more valuable test is to test that explicitly:

```
it('should ignore invalid values on a pristine input', function () {
  $scope.model.instanceName = 'this is an invalid name';
  form.instanceName.$setPristine();
  $scope.$digest();
  expect(form.instanceName.$valid).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: Apologies if upvote/accept was wonky - SO's app was having issues.  Should be resolved now.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use `$setViewValue` by referencing the form name and input name.

```
$scope.form.instanceName.$setViewValue('hello');
```

Then assert.

```
expect($scope.model.instanceName).toEqual('something');
expect($scope.form.instanceName.$valid).toBe(true);
```

Comment: `$setViewValue` triggers $parsers and $validators, not $formatters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController